# Laravel passport get new access token when the token is expired

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I want to implement a short time period of the token. Let say 1 day. Also I have `auth:api` middleware for my route:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('auth/test', 'AuthController@test');
```

When the token gets expired, the user gets logged out (with 401 response code) from the client. Which is not a good idea from the UX point of view. How can I handle it?

**Note:** I have already implemented such a scenario in CodeIgniter. I had an access token with 10 minutes of expiration time and a very long time refresh token (maybe one year). I had a reference of refresh token in the database. So, within 10 minutes, if the token is valid, there is no need to touch the database. If it's expired, I return a new token to the user, based on refresh token.

Answer (score 1):

One Approach could be to use [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware) on routes,this middleware would perform its task after the request is handled by the application. So in your middleware you can check if the response is 401(Unauthorize)  and if so then you can get expired token from header and regenerate new access token from expired token and return it to the user.

**Edit Another Approach**

If a user does not authenticate, Laravel will throw an `AuthenticationException`.

This exception is handled by the `render` method in `Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php`, and will in turn call the the `unauthenticated()` method which is defined in your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`: so you can wrote your logic in this method to generate new token from expired one and then return it to the user like

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    // generate new token and return it to the user and redirect user to the 
    //intended route.

    return redirect()->intended('defaultpage');
}
```

Comment: `auth:api` middleware won't let me to run After Middleware on my route.

Comment: @VahidNajafi i have edited my answer for another approach hope it helps you now

Comment: Thanks. Now I get the following error: `Could not check compatibility between App\\Exceptions\\Handler::unauthenticated($request, App\\Exceptions\\AuthenticationException $exception) and Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler::unauthenticated($request, Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthenticationException $exception), because class App\\Exceptions\\AuthenticationException is not available`

Comment: @VahidNajafi add `use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException`at top the file

Comment: @VahidNajafi be sure to include this above ```namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Response;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;```

Comment: @VahidNajafi do a `config:cache`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But I'm not sure how to redirect with a new token. Because of that, it fails with too many loops error.

Comment: Maybe that would be better to handle it in a custom middleware.